# How can I create a download link in octopress

Tags: octopress

I'm using Octopress for my blog and need to create a link to download a text file.

There is a built in plugin called include_code that renders a link but also shows the file. I just want the link. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your text file under `source/downloads/code`

Then you can use the markdown syntax for showing links like this :

```
[link name](url for the txt file)
```

The url will be `{your blog url}/downloads/code/{name of txt file}`

This is derived from the `include_code` plugin which also shows a download link for each code listing.

**UPDATE :**
To do it from within HTML, you can use

```
<a href ="{your blog url}/downloads/code/{name of txt file}">Text File</a>
```

Comment: Hi Ajay, I'm using it inside HTML because the layout is too complex for markdown, or my knowledge of it. This means the markdown isn't being rendered. Do you know of any other way I can do it?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I worked out what it is. It was actually because the plugin isn't setting the mime-type so if I change the file extension to .rb the download works fine but because it's a .js file the browser knows how to render it as a raw file i.e. it doesn't download. I think whoever wrote the plugin just overlooked this. I've left a GitHub issue so hopefully it will be fixed. I noticed that even on the include_code demo page the 'download' links were behaving in the same way.

Comment: It would be great if you could add the github issue link as a comment here.

Comment: You may need to add {{site.code_dir}} to the link as in here:
[link name]({{site.code_dir}}/name_of_txt_file)